# How to create a mesh with two shapekeys using extrude and bevel modifier?

Tags: animation, shape-keys, bevel, extrude

I tried all sorts of ways to make this work in the weekend but I didn't succeed. The problem is shapekeys and modifiers don't play together nicely. If I apply the bevel modifier after the shapekeys are created, then only one of the shapekeys are modified. If I apply the modifier before the two shapekeys are created, then I face the hard 3D problem of transforming the beveled shape to the other desired beveled shape.

So basically I would like to have a smooth animation of a mesh object that transforms from this shape:

[image]

to this shape:

[image]

while the shape is being extruded and beveled.

[image]

Comment: Do you have to apply the modifiers ? You can keep the Solidify + Bevel modifiers and it will adapt to the current shapekeys

Comment: To me it looks like as if the modifiers do not apply the same way to both shapekeys. Maybe the reason is that the bevel modifier cannot be applied the same way for the circle case and for the other case because they have different shapes.

Comment: Meanwhile I found that the bevel modifier produces a different bevel if the shape of the object changes. I guess that is understandable but it was confusing me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

**Animate the modifier props.**

To elaborate on [@Gorgeous' comment.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/213511/how-to-create-a-mesh-with-two-shapekeys-using-extrude-and-bevel-modifier#comment360252_213511)

Make your mesh, for example sake added a default circle, then grid filled. *Note to self,  rotate after grid fill to match axes before adding shape keys in future,*

Create your shape key from this. *Super fast hacked together example, showing my lack of modelling with bevel modifier, however shows proof of concept.*

[image]

Now add your modifiers to this object. Solidify and bevel.

[image]

any of the modifier properties can also be keyframed or driven.

[image]
*Ugly example, but you get the concept,  with solidify thickness being driven directly by shapekey value, and some bevel modifier properties too.*

Comment: interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a good case for the "Join as shapes" operation, which will make a shapekey from an entirely different object-- provided that both objects share the same topology.

Make your object, leaving the modifiers live.  Duplicate that object, then change the bevel modifier as desired.  Apply all modifiers to both objects.  Then select one object, shift select the other, and look on properties/object data/shapekeys.  From the shape key specials menu the right of the (empty) list of shapekeys, select "Join as shapes".  If the two objects share the same topology, it will create a shapekey for the active selection in the shape of the inactive selection.

If the objects do not share the same topology-- which is possible to get with different generative modifiers, part of the reason you can't apply modifiers on meshes with shapekeys-- then it will give you an error.  But if the objects do not share the same topology, it's impossible to do what you want as a shapekey in any fashion.